# solving 3 simultaneous 2nd order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have done first order simultaneous ODEs of this form, but only homogeneous so I am not sure how to vary my method for the equations below:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+k(2x-y)=0,\,\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+k(2y-x-z)=0,\,\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}+k(2z-y)=e^{-t}$$
It is the final equation being equal to $e^{-t}$ that puts me off. I started by putting it in the form:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=-k\begin{pmatrix}
2x-y\\2y-x-z\\2z-y
\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Which can then be rewritten as:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=-k\begin{pmatrix}
2&-1&0\\-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}$$
I would normally start by letting:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
X\\Y\\Z
\end{pmatrix}e^{\lambda t}$$
and finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M-I\lambda^2$, where $M$ is the matrix

EDIT:
The initial conditions are:
$$x(0)=x'(0)=y(0)=y'(0)=z(0)=z'(0)=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the Laplace Transform technique, Calling $X = (x,y,z)^{\dagger}$

$$
s^2 X(s) + k M X(s) = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ 0\\ \frac{1}{s+1}\end{array}\right)
$$

hence

$$
X(s) = \left(I_3 s^2+k M\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ 0\\ \frac{1}{s+1}\end{array}\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{k^2}{(s+1) \left(s^6+6 k s^4+10 k^2 s^2+4 k^3\right)}\\ 
\frac{k}{(s+1) \left(s^4+4 k s^2+2 k^2\right)} \\ 
\frac{\left(s^2+k\right) \left(s^2+3k\right)}{(s+1) \left(s^2+2 k\right) \left(s^4+4 k s^2+2 k^2\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I have never seen this technique before but have used Laplace transforms, thanks!